# Product topology and uniform topology on C[0,T]

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,T]}$ restricted to $C[0,T]$ (T finite) the same as the topology induced by the uniform norm on $C[0,T]$?

I am curious because I saw a claim on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Product_.CF.83-algebra) saying that the cylinder $\sigma$-algebra for $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ is a subalgebra of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the product topology of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ restricted to $X$. (Can anyone give a reference to this result?)

I know that the cylinder $\sigma$-algebra on $C[0,T]$ is the same as the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the uniform metric on $C[0,T]$; thus the result on wiki would imply the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the uniform topology is a subalgebra of that induced by the product topology. However, the uniform topology is usually finer than the product topology, so I am just wondering if they are actually the same in the case of $C[0,T]$ (or am I understanding something wrongly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product topology on $\mathbf{R}^{[0,T]}$ is the topology for which a sequence (or a *net*) in $\mathbf{R}^{[0,T]}$ converges if and only if all its projections to the component spaces $\mathbf{R}$ converges. This is the same as pointwise convergence of functions from $\mathbf{R}^{[0,T]}$. This topology is therefore called topology of pointwise convergence, or also simple convergence topology. Therefore, the topology on $\mathscr{C}([0,T],\mathbf{R})$ induced by the product topology on $\mathbf{R}^{[0,T]}$ is also the topology of simple convergence.

As a sequence converging uniformely to some function converges also simply to the same function, the uniform topology is coarser that the first one. And it is strictly coarser, as you're aware of the existence of sequences of functions converging simply but not uniformely.

Comment: Isn't the uniform topology finer than the product topology?